# VBA only running in debug mode

Tags: vba, image, excel

What I'm trying to do is to copy a bunch of cells as a picture from one sheet and paste it in a chart object in another sheet. The following is the code used and it is running fine when used in debug mode, but I do no see the image being pasted in the chart when I run it normally.

```
Sub copy_paste_KDT()
'
' copy_paste_KDT Macro
'

'
    Worksheets("KDT").Range("J12:AB37").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Dim wb_path As String
    wb_path = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

    'Dim objCht As ChartObject
    'Set objCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("KDT Rectangle")

    'If Not objCht Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("KDT Rectangle").Delete
    End If

    With Worksheets("profile")

        'Creating the Chart
        .ChartObjects.Add(690, 125, 550, 245).Name = "KDT Rectangle"

    End With

    If Range("B11").Value = 0 Then
        With Worksheets("profile")

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

            With .ChartObjects("KDT Rectangle")
                .Chart.Paste
            End With

        End With
    End If   
End Sub
```

I have also tried few thing like waiting for 1 to 10 seconds before the image is being pasted but of no use. Even tried putting a loop to count from 1 to a billion, no use again. Finally wanted to check if the image is getting pasted in a random cell of the sheet and that works, but not in the chart object.

I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out why the image is not getting paste.

TL,DR: Macro to copy paste a part of excel as a screenshot into a chart creates a chart successfully but not able to populate the image when run (F5), but works perfectly in debug mode (F8).

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have an issue with `activesheet` and `activeworkbook`?

Comment: @FunThomas the code is what I copy pasted as is and is working fine when running in debug mode (F8)

Comment: It worked for me. What excel version you are using?

Comment: Excel 2016 is what I'm using

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 and it work fine as well. When you use `Range("B11").Value = 0` it will take the value from the active page, rather add the specific `Sheet` you want to look at like `Worksheets("profile").Range("B11").Value = 0` . Also just try putting `.Select` before the `.Chart.Paste` just for testing to see if your chart is actually accessible.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen you are a genius. `.Select` did it for me. Please add it as an answer, will accept it. Also just an add on question but not a necessary one, is there a way of deselecting the chart object without selecting any cell on the sheet?

Comment: @StrikeR its not really possible, even when you add a sheet for the first time and you then activate that sheet the cell A1 becomes active. This is why we always want to avoid using `Select` and `Activate` and `ActiveSheet` and all the others. Using Variables and assigning them is the best and neatest way for the script to run.

Comment: @StrikeR remember to upvote the answer you choose to be correct as well or answer which you find that help you from other questions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am using Excel 2010 and your code works fine in testing for me.

You can try putting a `Select` in before the `.Chart.Paste` this might help with pasting inside the chart. See code below, just added the line into your original code, so you were almost there.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_paste_KDT()
'
' copy_paste_KDT Macro
'

'
    Worksheets("KDT").Range("J12:AB37").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Dim wb_path As String
    wb_path = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

    'Dim objCht As ChartObject
    'Set objCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("KDT Rectangle")

    'If Not objCht Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("KDT Rectangle").Delete
    End If

    With Worksheets("profile")

        'Creating the Chart
        .ChartObjects.Add(690, 125, 550, 245).Name = "KDT Rectangle"

    End With

    If Range("B11").Value = 0 Then
        With Worksheets("profile")

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

            With .ChartObjects("KDT Rectangle")
                .Select   'Just added this
                .Chart.Paste
            End With

        End With
    End If
End Sub
```